# Getting this error when deploying app to Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a simple page, when I load the page, I see this error in the console when the app is deployed to meteor

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ddp--6904-pipevine.meteor.com/sockjs/info?cb=vu7x9tcdcm. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://pipevine.meteor.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: It's hard to say without more information.  It would be helpful to see code if possible, know what browser you're testing with, which packages you're using, whether this is a new problem, etc.  I'd be happy to help directly - love to see other DC people using Meteor.  You can find me on twitter.

Comment: I'm testing with Chorme. I'm using collection2 and ironRouter. Its a very simple form submission. Intrestingly, the code works in my local environment when I run it. No issues but having issues when deploying to Modulus and Meteor.

Comment: I think it's related to the network errors that appear on page load, and so is reproducible without the form submission. You can see a bunch of canceled ddp requests.  Since very similar ddp requests work on other sites (http://roles.meteor.com/) it seems to be something specific to your project. You could try deploying a sample app, and then slowly copying over relevant stuff (packages, settings, etc) until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I just did some inspect element on: pipevine.meteor.com, and found the same result as @jrullmann, the error occurs when the page loads.

https://ddp--2488-pipevine.meteor.com/sockjs/info?cb=g70xkxrmob is a valid resource and gets redirected to (http)pipevine.meteor.com/sockjs/info?cb=g70xkxrmob, so there is no problem with the resource. Your SockJS also seems to be working fine on pipevine.meteor.com/sockjs

Again based on my guess, it could be the ironRouter or Collection2(AutoForm) problem, because I see that http://pipevine.meteor.com/:1 has the same problem as well.

On my second guess, can you try removing/commenting out the `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` from your html temporarily. And see if the error goes away on loading.

Comment: This is a good guess based on the error message, but I think there's more going on in this case.  Other projects deployed to meteor.com make cross-domain requests with ddp, without errors.  Here's an example: http://roles.meteor.com/

Comment: They use wss as the protocal. Not sure why it would switch for my form to https

Comment: @jrullmann I agree, there is a lot going on, I just edited my answer :) Its another guess.